# Изменить вид url для сайта

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect, mod-rewrite

У меня url  выглядит так `/portfolios/portfolio-1`, а мне нужно, чтобы оно выглядило просто `portfolio-1`, то есть нужно удалить из `url` папку `portfolios`, но при этом чтобы путь по факту оставался такой же

Когда я пытаюсь сделать `redirect` или `rewriterule` выдается страница 404

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html 

RewriteRule ^portfolio-(\d+) portfolios/portfolio-$1
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать?

Comment: а вы покажите, как вы это делаете

Comment: должно бы быть достаточно `RewriteRule ^portfolio-(\d+) portfolios/portfolio-$1`  если предполагается что там -1-2-3 и т.п

Comment: Redirect 301 /portfolios/portfolio-1 http://buildweb.best/portfolio-1 я делаю это так

Comment: Да, там 1,2,3 но это тоже не работает RewriteRule ^portfolio-(\d+) portfolios/portfolio-$1 , может быть я не в ту папку вложил .htaccess

Comment: не нужен вам там редирект 301й.

Comment: Структура сама такая: у меня в папке сайта есть папка portfolios и в ней лежат portfolio-1,-2 и так далее , файл .htaccess лежит тоже в папке с сайтом

Comment: Я пробовал и через rewriterule просто не так не так не получается

Comment: весь ваш htaccess приведите целиком

Comment: используйте [edit] для правки вопроса. не надо код вставлять в комментарии.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вставьте приведенное ниже правило в начало файла

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^(portfolio-\d+) portfolios/$1 [L, QSA]
 ...
 # остальные правила
```

Comment: Все равно на странице portfolio-1 открывается страница 404

Comment: @DanilapRock при условии того, что у вас там при попытке зайти на `/portfolios/portfolio-1` происходит 301й редирект на `/portfolio-1`, а в приведенном файле этого нет, то вы либо не тот файл правите, либо забыли его залить на сервер, либо еще что-то что не относится непосредственно к правилам.

Comment: Может как то влиять, что у файла portfolio-1 расширение .php и я его отключаю тоже через htaccess?

Comment: Просто сам путь без редиректа /portfolios/portfolio-1 страницу отрывает, а при редирект выдает 404

Comment: вы там в файле своем в угадайку играете что ли? если у вас `portfolio-1.php` называется, то редирект делать надо на `portfolios/$1.php` а  не пытаться к каждому запросу подставлять php/html. Закомментируйте свои правила и проверьте.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!! Поучилось